# CURL - simple example returning "CURLE_WRITE_ERROR"

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I am trying to run a simple example using libcurl, but just running this simple example gives me `CURLE_WRITE_ERROR` when I execute the `curl_easy_perform(...)` command. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? I have also tried other sites besides example.com.

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl) 
{
    CURLcode res;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl); // returns CURLE_WRITE_ERROR always!
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Comment: And where should CURL write the data it receives?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. To be honest, not sure what data it should receive or if I even expected data. Just wanted to execute a simple "ping the server" example to test libcurl.

Comment: Is this all the code? By default, libcurl uses `fwrite` to write to `STDOUT`.

Answer (score 5):

OK turns out Joachim is right. I did need a write callback

```
size_t CurlWriteCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{ 
    TRACE("CURL - Response received:\n%s", buf);
    TRACE("CURL - Response handled %d bytes:\n%s", size*nmemb);

    // tell curl how many bytes we handled
    return size*nmemb;
}

// ...

CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl) 
{
    CURLcode res;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &CurlWriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl); 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, and the "simple" example from libcurl does not specify this on their code. Thank you.